# Eloquent: get records with unique column value, with a fallback

Tags: mysql, eloquent

Let's say I have the following table:

```
id | name   | parent_id
-- | ------ | ---------
1  | monkey | NULL
2  | nut    | NULL
3  | mies   | NULL
4  | monkey | 1
5  | nut    | 1
```

Now I would like to get all records with a unique `name`, preferably with `parent_id = 1`, otherwise with `parent_id IS NULL`. So the result of the query will return records `[3, 4, 5]`.

How can this be achieved with Eloquent?

I already tried using `groupBy( 'name' )` in combination with `orderBy( 'entity_id', 'desc' )`, but `groupBy` seems to be executed before `orderBy`, so the result is always the same if I switch between `asc` and `desc` in the `orderBy` clause.

I also tried playing around with `distinct()` without any luck.

**UPDATE**

Of course, I can perform two queries and merge the results, but I was wondering if this could be done with a single query.

**UPDATE 2**

Currently, I solved it with the `unique()` method on Eloquent's `Collection` class:

```
$parent = Parent::find( 1 );
$items  = $parent->items()
                 ->orWhereNull( 'parent_id' )
                 ->orderBy( 'parent_id', 'desc' )
                 ->get()
                 ->unique( 'name' );
```

Comment: raw query would do?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1:**

You need to `GROUP BY` `name` first while using `aggregate` function like `MAX` on `parent_id`. Thus your preference is reserved.

Later while joining on the `max_parent_id` you need to check for `NULL`. Because `NULL` can only be compared using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` in `MySQL`. If the `max_parent_id` of a `name` is `NULL` then you should allow it in your final result set(see how the `IF` is used in this case)

---

```
SELECT 
 YT.*
FROM your_table YT 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
     name,
     MAX(parent_id) AS max_parent_id 
    FROM your_table
    --WHERE parent_id IS NULL OR parent_id IN (1)
    GROUP BY name
) AS t
ON YT.name = t.name AND 
   IF(t.max_parent_id IS NULL, TRUE, YT.parent_id = t.max_parent_id);
```

[**See Demo**](http://rextester.com/RQPQ14837)

---

**Approach #2:**

Using `MySQL user-defined variables` you can achieve this too.

<sub>**Approach #2** scales</sub>

```
SELECT 
t.id,
t.name,
t.parent_id
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        IF(@prev_name = name, @rn := @rn + 1,
           IF(@prev_name := name, @rn := 1, @rn := 1)
           ) AS rank,
        your_table.*
    FROM your_table 
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
        SELECT @rn := 0, @prev_name := NULL
    ) AS var
    ORDER BY name, parent_id DESC
) AS t
WHERE t.rank = 1
ORDER BY t.id;
```

[**See Demo**](http://rextester.com/PZLS64016)

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed. The problem is it takes the highest `parent_id` while in my scenario there will be a given `parent_id`. I'm not quite sure how to fit that into the first approach.

Comment: Could u please be more elaborate?

Comment: I've added a where clause in the inner query of the first approach. Please check whether this works for you